# A subgroup generated by two noncommuting elements in a group

Tags: group-theory

Let the "rational unit circle" be 
$$ RS^1 = \{ e^{i \theta \pi} \, |\, \theta \in \mathbb{Q}\}.$$

Let $G$ be the group of linear functions, 
$$ G = \{\varphi(z)=az+b \, | \, a\in RS^1, b\in \mathbb{C} \},$$
(that is, linear functions which are "rational"-rotation + translation) where multiplication is function composition.

Clearly, we may view $G$ as the set of pairs
$$ G = \{ (a,b) \, | \, a\in RS^1, b\in \mathbb{C}\},$$
and define multiplication as
$$ (a_1,b_1) \cdot (a_2,b_2) = (a_1 a_2, a_1 b_2 + b_1).$$

**Question:** Suppose $\varphi_1,\varphi_2\in G$ do not commute. What is the subgroup they generate.

Any comments regarding the structure of this group are welcome.

P.s. In a previous formulation of the problem, I defined 
$$ G = \{ (a,b) \, | \, (a+1)\in RS^1, b\in \mathbb{C}\},$$
with multiplication:
$$ (a_1,b_1) \cdot (a_2,b_2) = (a_1 a_2 + a_1 +a_2, a_1 b_2 + b_1 +b_2).$$
DonAntonio's answer below refers to this older formulation.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is this done for the rational unit circle, instead of the entire circle?

Comment: It may be extended to the whole unit circle; it will still be a group. I'm only interested in the rational case for a problem I'm trying to solve.

Comment: Why not take $RS^1\times \mathbb C$ with $(a_1,b_1)\cdot (a_2,b_2) = (a_1 a_2, a_1b_2+b_1)$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen You're right. I actually over complicated the problem for no reason. I'll withdraw my question, and think it over.

Answer (score 1):

It is easy, and only slightly messy, to show by induction that

$$(a,b)^n=\begin{cases}\left((a+1)^n-1\;,\;\frac{(a+1)^n-1}{a}b\right)&,\;\; a\neq 0\\{}\\{}\\{.}\\{.}\\(0,nb)&,\;\;\,a=0\end{cases}$$

Perhaps this helps a little and later, maybe, I'll add something else

**Added:** Let us take for example the non-commuting elements $\,(-2,1)\,,\,(0,1)\,$:

$$(-2,1)^2=\left((-1)^2-1\;,\;\frac{(-1)^2-1}{-2}\right)=(0,0)\Longrightarrow \mathcal Ord(-2,1)=2$$

and since clearly

$$\mathcal Ord(0,1)=\infty$$

We have that $

$$\langle\,(-2,1)\,,\,(0,1)\,\rangle\cong\Bbb Z\rtimes C_2=\,\text{infinite dihedral group}$$

with the inversion action:

$$(0,1)^{(-2,1)}=(0,-1)=(0,1)^{-1}$$

Comment: My apologies. I changed the notation after the answer was posted. In the new notation, DonAntonio's answer is:
$$(a,b)^n=\begin{cases}\left(a^n\;,\;\frac{a^n-1}{a-1}b\right)&,\;\; a\neq 1\\{}\\{}\\{.}\\{.}\\\(0,nb)&,\;\;\,a=1\end{cases}$$

Comment: Why did you do that? It probably would have been better to leave the original question (which was pretty interesting imfho) and open a new thread, wouldn't it? And the upper lime in your comment above is wrong: that is not what is written in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You mean the lower line should be $(1,nb)$, correct ?
Again, I'm sorry for pulling the notation under your answer.

Comment: No, it is $\,(0,1)^n=(0,nb)\,$ , according to the first definition of the product you gave.